# Using Entity Core with VS 2015 with .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I am using Visual Studio 2015. And I am develop app with Entity.Core.
But I am getting error while using Add-migration command.

I identified my models.

But getting error using the command "Add-migration TestDb" with Nuget Package Console.

> Startup project 'src\WebApplication1' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core
>   project for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework
>   Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of
>   projects.

How can I solve it.
And I don't want to Visual Studio 2017. Please do not recommend that.
The same operations I can do on my other computer.

I've update my question with project.json.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your project.json. You probably have a too new version of the tools for EF in your project.json. But not wanting to switch to VS2017 will block you sooner or later, all new development of the build pipeline and VS Tools will only happen on VS2017. The tools for VS2015 won't be updated anymore. Also you will unlikely have access to the soon to be released .NET Core 2.0/NETStandard 2.0 if you stay at VS2015

Comment: I've update my question with project.json upon your request.

Comment: You didn't even added the tools. You only have them as dependency, but not registered as tools

Comment: actually i've added. but i cannot see it.
==
Cannot execute this command because 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' is not installed in project 'src\WebApplication1'. Add 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' to the 'tools' section in project.json. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for more details.
==

Comment: actually, you're right. I think it is necessary to install an older version.

Comment: The tools marked preview2 should be the latest one which support VS2015, which would be https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/1.0.0-preview2-final. You can still use them with EF Core 1.1 iirc. But like I said, all new versions of the tools etc won't run with VS2015

Answer (score 1):

Docs for EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Make sure you read the documentation.

So you are getting that error probably for 2 reasons:

1)In your `project.json` file make sure you have `EntityFrameworkCore.Design/Tools` added in you dependencies and `EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` in your tools.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    }.
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
```

2) Once you sorted the above issue this will allow you to use the appropriate commands in your cli (PM Console) make sure you are in the project directory:

- Create Migration: `dotnet ef migrations add <name>`
- Update Database: `dotnet ef database update`

Comment: Please note, there is no EF7, which you can already see with the project.json dependencies you have posted. It's called EF Core and it's not limited to .NET Core just because it has "Core" in it's name, you can also use it against .NET Framework >=4.5

Comment: actually correct, but it is cannot solve my problem. I think something else is going wrong.

Comment: @caras can you update your question with your current `project.json` file, and are you getting a different error now?

Comment: My one didn't work with this combination, it maybe because my .NetCore is a bit older, for me I used `1.0.1` instead of `1.1.0` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error on `PM> Update-Database`. If you have the latest version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (1.1.1 is the latest stable version when I posted this answer) and you are using VS2015, try to downgrade to

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final

Install from package manager : `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 1.1.0-preview4-final -Pre`

My package.json looks like this :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.2",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Hope it helps anyone.